# What can we do to handle historical tagging issues with the python tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The current tag wiki for [python](/questions/tagged/python) says:

> ### Tagging recommendation:
>
> Use the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag for all Python related questions. If you believe your question includes issues specific to the incompatible Python 2.x or Python 3.x, in addition to the main [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag, use [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) or [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x). If you believe your question may be even more specific, you can include a version specific tag such as [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

Thus we currently have 196,054 questions tagged *python* but only 378 and 6,008 questions tagged *python-2.x* and *python-3.x* respectively.

Sadly I have recently noticed that questions and answers using the *python* tag are **significantly devalued** by the fact that often neither specify which version of the language they are referring to.

The differences between Python 2 and Python 3 are significant enough that in many cases the answers for each language are worlds apart, especially in the realm of [unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode) support.

Questioners frequently don't mention which version of python they are using, and even if it is clear from context which they are using then answers often make their own assumptions and fail to mention what those assumptions are.

This makes looking for answers to many python questions time consuming and highly frustrating. When I search for answers to *java* or *C#* questions I expect to get the answer I'm looking for in the first few hits, with *python* my hit rate is substantially lower.

So, what can we do to make the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag more useful? How can we make it easier to filter by language version when the vast majority of questions aren't version tagged and the tag wiki has such a relaxed attitude to version tagging?

Answer (score 2):

This is something the Python community have to do themselves, if they want to. There's no magic wand unfortunately.

Your problem is analogous to the SQL tag. Every single time someone posts a question with only the tag SQL one of two things happens:

- If it's obvious what RDBMS the OP is using the question gets tagged with that as well
- If it's not obvious then someone comments and asks the OP. If the OP responds the question gets tagged. If the OP doesn't respond and knowledge of the RDBMS is critical then the question gets downvoted and eventually closed. Not answering the question makes it more likely the question will gain downvotes and/or close votes.

There are almost no exceptions.

If the Python community wants to fix the tagging (assuming there is something that needs fixing) they need to be doing the same thing.

- Every single, relevant, question gets a version tag.
- Users with enough reputation tag the question if it's obvious with the correct version.
- Everyone comments, on every question asking what version the OP is using (if it's not obvious).

You can do this to. If you see a question where its not obvious, comment yourself. You'll help everyone in the longer run.